# QuickTime movie disappearing from Javascript when scrolled offscreen in non-Safari Mac browsers?

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, google-chrome, quicktime

I have a web page I'm creating that uses Javascript to control an embedded QuickTime player. I add the QuickTime movie to the page using the AC_QuickTime.js file from Apple (as described here - http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001525-2-SW1 ). Everything seems to be working fine - I can call methods on the QuickTime movie and control its playback (as well as get the current timestamp).

The problem is that on the Mac in Firefox, Camino, and Chrome, when I scroll down such that the QuickTime player is no longer visible, any method calls on the QuickTime movie no longer work. Some method calls (e.g. GetPluginStatus()) throw an error, like:

> Error calling method on NPObject!

Other method calls just return nothing useful. For instance, calling GetTime() returns the current time of the movie until the video scrolls off screen, and then returns 0. You can see a simple example of this here: http://www.usefulfruit.com/temp/fftest/ . Just click the Play link, then scroll down until the video is no longer visible.

This does not occur in Safari on the Mac or in any browser I've tested on Windows. Why is this happening, and is there any way to work around this?

Comment: I had this same issue, I believe this is a problem with QuickTime.

Answer (score 0):

Why not html5 video? ( safari, chrome works )

```
<video src="recording.mp4">
     // is not supported, insert Flash 
     <object
       classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
       codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0"
       width="550" height="400">
       <param name="movie" value="YOU_FLASH_PLAYER.swf" />
       <param name="quality" value="high" />
       <embed src="YOU_FLASH_PLAYER.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="550" height="400"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
       </embed>
     </object>
    </video>
```